# Cypher - Input to subquery without fabric?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Based on this [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/index.html#subquery-correlated-importing), one way to make a variable visible within a subquery is using `WITH` keyword:

```
UNWIND ['Hotels', 'Hostels'] as cat_name
CALL {
    WITH cat_name
    MATCH (:Category {category_id: cat_name})<-[:IN_CATEGORY]-(:Business)<-[:REVIEWS]-(:Review)<-[:WROTE]-(u:User)
    RETURN DISTINCT cat_name, u.name AS name, u.pageRank20 AS pageRank20
    ORDER BY u.pageRank20 DESC
    LIMIT 10
}
RETURN cat_name, name, pageRank20
```

...got `Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError`: `Importing variables into subqueries is not available in this implementation of Cypher due to lack of support for correlated subqueries.`

Enabling [Fabric](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/fabric/introduction/) feature is an overkill here. (I don't want to get **Data Federation** involved for a simple dataset)

One workaround is to use `UNION` ([link](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/)). However, if having too many, e.g. cat_name, copying & pasting a lot for `UNION` doesn't look good (although it is do-able).

**Question**: Is there any other way to fulfil the intention of the query above (input a variable into subqueries), without leveraging `fabric` and `UNION`?

Environment: Neo4j Desktop v4.0.4, Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: You could use apoc.cypher.run... also if you want to limit by row like in the example you can use collect(item)[..10]

Comment: To note, correlated subqueries are on the way, separate from the current Fabric implementation. In the meantime you can use `apoc.cypher.run()`, as Tomaz suggested, or `apoc.cypher.doIt()`, if the subquery needs to write to the graph.

Comment: @InverseFalcon So true. This feature is "likely to show up with a 4.1.0 minor release" ([link](https://community.neo4j.com/t/cypher-subqueries-why-cant-subqueries-refer-to-variables-from-the-enclosing-query/16359))

Comment: @JoyfulPanda 4.1.0 is out, and correlated subqueries are in! You can try it out, though keep in mind that the subquery cannot return any variables that already exist in the outer query (including any that were used as inputs to the subquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use case does not actually require subqueries. For example:

```
MATCH (c:Category)<-[:IN_CATEGORY]-(:Business)<-[:REVIEWS]-(:Review)<-[:WROTE]-(u:User)
WHERE c.category_id IN ['Hotels', 'Hostels']
WITH c, u
ORDER BY u.pageRank20 DESC
WITH c.category_id AS cat_name, COLLECT(DISTINCT u)[..10] AS users
UNWIND users AS user
RETURN cat_name, user.name AS name, user.pageRank20 AS pageRank20
```

Comment: Your solution works well. But I have a concern that this solution uses much more memory as it first expands all combinations (from `Category` to `User`). It only cuts off the top 10 for each category later. In case of subquery, I assume each subquery is executed sequentially. When the latter subquery is being run, the former one only keeps top 10 elements.

Comment: A valid concern, and you can use PROFILE to check that. Even if it is not performant now, though, it *should* be possible for the Cypher planner to improve in the future to intelligently avoid creating a complete collection when not needed.